# Splitting a Line on a Polygon QGIS 2.10

Tags: qgis, splitting, qgis-2.10

I am currently creating a polyline shapefile and need to split a line so as to add in a new off shoot. Would anyone happen to know how to split a polyline in QGIS?

I have tried the split features tool in the advanced digitising toolbar with the following result. It is split at the node but the rest of the line is aligned to a new bearing and the parent section I wanted keeping was lost.

[image]

Comment: Did you also use the Menu option of: Vector -> Data Management Tools ->  Split Vector Layer ?

Comment: Do I have to have the nodes I want to split at selected for that to work?

Comment: No. Select the vector layer, the Unique ID field and the Output Folder. If your vector layer has, e.g., 34 features you will get 34 vector layers (one for each feature).

Comment: I have just done that. In the directory I sent it to it spat out a single shape file. Im guessing that was an unwanted result? In all other regards it appears to be the same shapefile.

Comment: Please, edit your question and put an image of your attributes table.

Comment: Ive attached the table. Surely there's a simpler way of splitting a polyline.

Comment: The problem is that your table needs an ID value for each feature that you want to split.

Comment: Ah. Is this the only way to split the line?; As adding in id's for each of the features could take some time/

Comment: It is quick and easy with the field calculator.

Comment: Right, i've given the three polyline sections numbers 1 2 and 3. How would you do it via the calc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, it looks like there was something odd with the layer I was working with which I'll put down to it being imported from Mapinfo's FME converter. In a test environment I created a new poly line. Activated the advanced digitising toolbar. Clicked on the split features button and then clicked either side of the test line with a right click to complete the split.